# Entidade Endereco Compatilhada

Tags: classes, ddd

Modelando um projeto associei uma entidade **Endereco** na Raiz de Agregação **Cliente**. Até aí tudo bem. Contudo, verifiquei posteriormente que outras entidades ou raízes de agregação como **Empresa** e **Fornecedor** também precisam de endereço na sua composição. Sendo assim, a dúvida que tenho é como utilizar a mesma entidade Endereço para atender a todas entidades que necessitem dela?
Obs: a modelagem que estou fazendo é baseada nos conceitos de DDD.

Comment: Qual linguagem você esta utilizando? Como está seu código?

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr

Você modelou a entidade Endereço como entidade filha de Cliente, porém ela é apenas uma entidade relacionada.

#### Entendendo o que é um endereço

Normalmente, quando estou desenhando um conceito, sinto a necessidade de ser cético sobre ele, ou seja, por em dúvida aquilo que conheço dele. Assim, geralmente acabo descobrindo algo novo que muda o design.

Dito isto, o melhor a se fazer é compreender como  os [Correios identificam](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endere%C3%A7o_postal) [um endereço](http://www.buscacep.correios.com.br/sistemas/buscacep/cepFormas.cfm). O que reproduzo abaixo para fins históricos:

1. Nome do destinatário
2. Nome do logradouro (uma rua ou avenida), número da residência, complemento (geralmente um número de apartamento)
3. Nome do bairro (opcional)
4. Nome da cidade e nome do estado
5. CEP.
6. Latitude e Longitude

O item 1 nós normalmente atribuímos a outra entidade, como, no seu caso, Cliente, Empresa e Fornecedor. Já o item 6 é imutável porque uma latitude e longitude diferentes representam um endereço/local diferente.

Com relação aos itens que vão de 2 a 5, todos podem ser alterados. Exemplos:

- O nome de um logradouro (que foi escrito incorretamente no sistema ou que foi alterado pela prefeitura)
- Um bairro que foi criado
- Um distrito que se tornou uma nova cidade
- O formato do CEP, [que foi alterado em 1992](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_de_Endere%C3%A7amento_Postal).

Em qualquer um dois exemplos acima nós, desenvolvedores e usuários, queremos que, uma vez que um atributo tenha sido alterado, o novo valor seja aplicado para todos que utilizam aquele atributo. Ou seja, se uma rua trocou de nome, o desejável é que o novo nome seja aplicado a todos os clientes e fornecedores que residam lá.

Isso nos mostra que um endereço tem um ciclo de vida e que, se um de seus atributos mudar, ele ainda pode ser o mesmo endereço. **Logo, endereço é uma entidade, não um objeto de valor.**

#### Entidades filhas e entidades relacionadas

**Entidades filhas** são aquelas cujo ciclo de vida está diretamente ligado ao da entidade pai, como, por exemplo, um projeto e uma tarefa (task). Uma terefa existe apenas dentro de um projeto e, quando um projeto é deletado, a tarefa também é.

**Entidades relacionadas** são aquelas que estão ligadas a outras entidades mas tem um ciclo de vida independente, como, por exemplo, endereços.

[Referência](http://verraes.net/2013/12/related-entities-vs-child-entities/)

Por fim, um agregado pode conter entidade pai, entidades filhas e objetos de valor. Um agregado não deve conter entidades relacionadas.

Comment: Olá Tobias, na verdade eu tenho no banco de dados apenas uma tabela chamada Endereco e na aplicação a sua modelagem. Acho que me expressei mal quando disse "...como utilizar a mesma entidade Endereço para atender a todas entidades". Eu gostaria de ter uma só tabela  no banco e nela guardar endereços vindo de todos os lugares possíveis (contudo cada endereço pertencente a um dono que pode ser uma empresa, um cliente, um fornecedor, etc)... meu raciocínio é adequado ou tem uma foma mais elegante de normalizar esse cenário?...

Comment: @MarceloAlmeida está tudo certo, o que você comentou agora é o mesmo que eu havia compreendido da sua pergunta inicial. O seu caso de uso é o que eu descrevi no terceiro paragrafo da minha resposta.
O banco de dados está certo, o que precisa mudar é a arquitetura do seu código: coloque a entidade Endereço no mesmo nível hierarquico de Cliente e acesse Endereço através do repository de Cliente (i.e. não utilize seu ORM para acessar Endereço diretamente de Cliente, caso seu ORM seja Active Record)

Comment: @MarceloAlmeida editei a resposta para dexá-la mais clara. Veja se tens alguma dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Pode sim, a classe endereço irá usar a convenção de ValueObject em um diretório dentro do seu domínio. Porém seria correto você persistir (banco de dados) em tabelas separadas e relacionadas em seu respectivos domínios ou até mesmo utilizar as tabelas da entidades principais da agregação. O ValueObject é imutável, então por exemplo, ao adicionar um novo endereço você deverá remover o atual e adicionar o novo, para isso é "permitido" criar comportamentos que lhe auxiliam nesse cenário e os mesmos só podem ser acessados da entidade root da agregação que a utiliza.

Material para conhecimento:

- https://deviq.com/value-object/
- https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects
- https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html